# Remove multiple elements from a flat array using whitelisted values

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, array-intersect

I have an array like this:

```
$categories_array = ['category_1', 'category_2', 'category_3', 'category_4'];
```

I'd like to filter the array to get a new one. For example, I'd like to have a new array with only `category_2` and `category_3` and preserve the original keys like this:

```
$new_categories_array = [1 => 'category_2', 2 => 'category_3'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

- [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) — Computes the difference of arrays
- [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) — Computes the intersection of arrays

Example:

```
$original = array('category_1','category_2','category_3','category_4');
$new      = array_diff($original, array('category_1', 'category_4'));

print_r($new);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => category_2
    [2] => category_3
)
```

When using `array_intersect` the returned array would contain cat 1 and 4 obviously.

Comment: This is a good solution, but is it possible to tell the script the elements to "save" instead of the elements that will be removed?

Comment: @Pennywise see update. you want `array_intersect` in that case.

Answer (score 3):

```
unset($new_categories_array[0]);
unset($new_categories_array[3]);
```

..might do the trick

Comment: mmm... that should work but I'd like to write a function where I can set the name of elements that I want to save, not to exclude.

Something like this:
my_function('category_2, category_3', $original_array);

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_grep`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$new_categories_array = preg_grep('/category_[23]/', $categories_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree `preg_grep` is a good solution in your example, if you want a more general case function, look at `array_filter` - http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php